# pypi: registering a modified version of a python package

Tags: python, pypi, pypiserver

I am trying to register a modified version of a python package which already exists in pypi called cutadapt.

Any suggestions on how to do that? I thought I would give the package a different name in the minimum amount of places required, then submit the modified package with the modified code. The code comes from a fork I did of the original package.

I have edited the `setup.py` file and changed the `name` of the package like so:

```
setup(
    name = 'new_name',
[...]
    packages = ['orig_name',orig_name.scripts'],
    scripts = ['bin/orig_name'],
```

I didn't change the name in the `packages` and the `scripts` section, since the name of those files is still the same, even if the code is modified.

I tried to register this package but got a `Invalid header format` from this command:

```
python setup.py register -r pypitest
running register
running check
Registering cutadapt_brc to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (503): Invalid header format
```

But I am guessing this could be an authentication error rather than due to the modified naming I am trying to achieve. Any ideas what's wrong?